# no output from running this code, is there an infinite loop?

Tags: c

It seems I have an infinite loop in here, nothing seems to happen when I run it. I'm not sure if I am even starting the process right because nothing happens.

objective->
1. Write a function struct student* allocate () that allocates memory for ten students and returns the pointer.
2. Write a function void generate (struct student* students) that generates random IDs and scores for each of the ten students and stores them
in the array of students. Ensure that IDs are unique also and between 1 and 10 (both inclusive) and scores are between 0 and 100 (both
inclusive). To generate unique IDs you can either use the brute-force random/check/repeat (generate a random integer between 1- 10 and then
confirm that it hasn't been used yet for a student ID) or you can use the Fisher Yates shuffle -(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%
93Yates_shuffle).
3. Write a function void output (struct student* students) that prints the IDs and scores of all the students. The output of the function needs not
to be sorted.
4. Write a function void summary (struct student* students) that prints the minimum score, maximum score and average score of the ten
students.
5. Write a function void deallocate (struct student* stud) that frees the memory allocated to students. Check that students is not NULL (NULL
== 0) before you attempt to free it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

struct student{
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct student* allocate(){
     /*Allocate memory for ten students*/
     struct student * students = malloc(10* sizeof(struct student));
    return students;
     /*Return the pointer*/
}

void generate(struct student* students){
     /*Generate random and unique IDs and random scores for ten students, 
IDs being between 1 and 10, scores between 0 and 100*/
    int j;
    int k;
    int i;
    int listScore[100];
    int listId[10];

    for(k=1; k<=10;k++)
        {listId[k]= -1;}    
    for(j=1; j<=100;k++)
        {listScore[j]= -1;}
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     int y = i+(rand() % (10-i));
     int temp = listId[i];
     listId[i] = listId[j];
     listId[j]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        students[i].id = listId[i];  
    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
     int y = i+(rand() % (100-i));
     int temp = listScore[i];
     listScore[i] = listScore[j];
     listScore[j]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        students[i].score = listScore[i];  
    }
}

void output(struct student* students){
    int i;
    printf("ID1 Score%d\n",students[1].score);
    for(i=2; i<=10; i++ )
    {
        printf("ID%d score%d\n", i, students[i].score);
    }
    /*Output information about the ten students in the format:
              ID1 Score1
              ID2 score2
              ID3 score3
              ...
              ID10 score10*/
}

void summary(struct student* students){
    int i;
    int min = students[1].score;
    int max= students[1].score;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(students[i].score < min)
        {
            min = students[i].score;
        }
    }
    for(i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(students[i].score >max)
        {
            max = students[i].score;
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        sum += students[i].score;
    }
    sum /=10;
    printf("Minimum score = %d\nMaximum score = %d\nAverage score = %d",min,max,sum);
    /*Compute and print the minimum, maximum and average scores of the 
ten students*/

}

void deallocate(struct student* stud){
     /*Deallocate memory from stud*/
    if(stud != NULL)
    {
        free(stud);
    }
}
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    struct student* stud = NULL;

    /*Call allocate*/
    stud = allocate();
    /*Call generate*/
    generate(stud);
    /*Call output*/
    output(stud);
    /*Call summary*/
    summary(stud);
    /*Call deallocate*/
    deallocate(stud);
    return 0;
}

/* CS261- Assignment 1 - Q.1*/
/* Name:
 * Date:
 * Solution description:
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

struct student{
    int id;
    int score;
};

struct student* allocate(){
     /*Allocate memory for ten students*/
     struct student * students = malloc(10* sizeof(struct student));
    return students;
     /*Return the pointer*/
}

void generate(struct student* students){
     /*Generate random and unique IDs and random scores for ten students, 
IDs being between 1 and 10, scores between 0 and 100*/
    int j;
    int k;
    int i;
    int listScore[100];
    int listId[10];

    for(k=1; k<=10;k++)
        {listId[k]= -1;}    
    for(j=1; j<=100;k++)
        {listScore[j]= -1;}
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     int y = i+(rand() % (10-i));
     int temp = listId[i];
     listId[i] = listId[j];
     listId[j]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        students[i].id = listId[i];  
    }
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
     int y = i+(rand() % (100-i));
     int temp = listScore[i];
     listScore[i] = listScore[j];
     listScore[j]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        students[i].score = listScore[i];  
    }
}

void output(struct student* students){
    int i;
    printf("ID1 Score%d\n",students[1].score);
    for(i=2; i<=10; i++ )
    {
        printf("ID%d score%d\n", i, students[i].score);
    }
    /*Output information about the ten students in the format:
              ID1 Score1
              ID2 score2
              ID3 score3
              ...
              ID10 score10*/
}

void summary(struct student* students){
    int i;
    int min = students[1].score;
    int max= students[1].score;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(students[i].score < min)
        {
            min = students[i].score;
        }
    }
    for(i=2;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(students[i].score >max)
        {
            max = students[i].score;
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        sum += students[i].score;
    }
    sum /=10;
    printf("Minimum score = %d\nMaximum score = %d\nAverage score = %d",min,max,sum);
    /*Compute and print the minimum, maximum and average scores of the 
ten students*/

}

void deallocate(struct student* stud){
     /*Deallocate memory from stud*/
    if(stud != NULL)
    {
        free(stud);
    }
}
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    struct student* stud = NULL;

    /*Call allocate*/
    stud = allocate();
    /*Call generate*/
    generate(stud);
    /*Call output*/
    output(stud);
    /*Call summary*/
    summary(stud);
    /*Call deallocate*/
    deallocate(stud);
    return 0;
}
```

enter code here

Comment: Arrays start with index `0` and go to index `n - 1`. You're considering `listId[1]` through `listId[10]` ... ignoring `listId[0]` and trying to access the inexistent `listId[10]` (the same for `listScore[]`). Same error with `students[]` in `output()` and `summary()`.

Comment: ...similarly when initialising `listScore`.

Comment: Now would be a good time for you to learn how to use a debugging tool

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're incrementing wrong variable here

```
for(j=1; j <= 100; k++) {
    listScore[j]= -1;
}
```

Try using `j++` instead of `k++`.

Comment: This is probably the immediate cause of the infinite loop. @OP: read the comments and mind them!

Comment: Sorry.. Didn't have enough rep to comment.

Comment: @ETO well, I think it does. Ending the answer with a question is probably a poor wording, but all in all, it __is__ an answer.

Comment: @ManojVadehra Alright. Pls avoid asking questions in your answers. Write a comment if you want to clarify something.

Comment: @ETO FYI - this is not "my" answer. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, Yup :)

Answer (score 0):

in 158th line you increment the wrong variable causing the loop running infinite time.

```
for(j=1; j<=100;k++)
{listScore[j]= -1;}
```